# Как закрыть всплывающее модульное окно и вывести другое?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fancybox, всплывающее-окно

Есть сайт с несколькими формами для отправки обратной связи. Одна находится во всплывающем окне, другие - открытые и помещены в тело сайта.

Необходимо сделать, чтобы после отправки формы (отправка письма через php во фрейме выполняется) имеющееся модальное окно заменилось другим (оно уже отверстано и имеет id='result'>

Такая же задача и для других форм (открытых). Человек оставил данные, кликнул на кнопку - вместо полей для ввода, кнопки и заголовка появилась просто надпись с благодарностью (вместо самой формы!).

Надеюсь, объяснил понятно :)

Плюс очень бы хотелось подправить php-файл с отправкой данных. Сейчас там прикручен редирект после оформления заказа, удалось его "победить" путем установки:

```
<iframe name="iframe1" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;"></iframe>
```

И прописывания target="iframe1" форме.

Что именно необходимо скидывать сюда (из кодов) не знаю, поэтому скину ссылку на сайт: http://amixshop.ru/coldcalls/test/

P.S. Js, jQuery, Ajax, fancybox не использовались :) Если подскажете, как их использовать здесь (или куда копать за ответом) буду очень благодарен!

Comment: http://xozblog.ru/demo/modal-windows/ - пример

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Stack Overflow на русском - не фриланс биржа. Если у вас возник конкретный вопрос, пожалуйста, [задайте](/questions/ask) его сообществу.

Comment: Хорошо, Вас понял!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу по второму вопросу:
Учебник по jQuery для начинающих: http://habrahabr.ru/post/155107/

Ответ на первый вопрос:
Запрос на сервер из форм очень часто делают с использованием технологии Ajax (http://habrahabr.ru/post/14246/). После прочтения статьи, я думаю все станет немного понятней.

Надо сделать что-то подобное:

1. После того как отсылается запрос на сервер из формы, код на сервере возвращает какой-нибудь статус, о том, что данные приняты.
2. В `callback` функции запроса, в скрипте, если получаем правильный статус от сервера, берем первую форму и скрываем (например, так `document.getElelmentById("formId").style.display = "none";`) и заставляем появиться форму с результатом (например, так `document.getElelmentById("result").style.display = "block";`)

Надо заметить, что в этих примерах я использую чистый Javascript. С jQuery, например, все будет чуть удобнее.

Конечно же можно сделать и более оптимально, но для представления о том куда копать у вас есть :)